# How to configure active directory running on Virtual machine

Tags: windows, active-directory

I have active directory installed on a Virtual Machine having OS Win Server 2012.
Now I want to configure it so that users can access it.

My IP Add is: 103.31.80.54
Subnet Mask:  255.255.255.252
GW:           103.31.80.53

What to do??

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below mentioned steps from the Server Manager on Windows 2012 Server:

- Open the Notifications Pane by selecting the Notifications icon from the top of the Server Manager. From the notification regarding configuring AD DS click

Promote this server to a domain controller.

- From the Deployment Configuration tab select Add a new forest from the radial options menu. Insert your root domain name into the Root domain name field. [i.e

yourdomain.com]

- Review and select a Domain and Forest functional level. Once selected fill in a DSRM password in the provided password fields. The DSRM password is used when

booting the Domain Controller into recovery mode.

- Review the warning on the DNS Options tab and select Next.
- Confirm or enter a NetBIOS name and click Next.
- Configure the location of the SYSVOL, Log files, and Database folders and click Next.
- Review the configuration options and click Next.
- The system will check to ensure all necessary prerequistes are installed on the system prior to moving forward. If the system passes these checks you will

proceed by clicking Install. [The server will automatically be rebooted once the installation completes]

- Once the server is done rebooting reconnect via RDP. Congratulations on successfully installing and configuring a Active Directory Domain Services on Windows

Server 2012.